# wordpress after custom image upload in a custom directory, finding the image address

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading, jquery-forms-plugin

I used jQuery [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to upload image in a newly created directory(i.e. my_gallery) within the theme file. How can I get the uploaded image address ?

Answer (score 0):

yes got the answer. Pretty easy. The address is:

```
get_template_directory_uri()."/my_gallery/imagename"
```